# Linux - How to program for a touchscreen outside of X Windows

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, framebuffer, touchscreen

I have a small TFT with touch control connected to a Raspberry Pi. The touchscreen works well within X windows.

I would like to be able to use the touchscreen outside of X windows.
Something simple, like two buttons on the screen.

I have experience with C and writing to the framebuffer using SDL. Or directly to memory.

I have no idea how to detect the input of the touchscreen and I am hoping some one could point me in the right direction.

I see the touchscreen as /dev/input/event0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are just seeing a regular event device. What have you done so far? You might try for example [Using the Input Subsystem](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6429) article on Linux Journal.

What you should try at first should probably be:

```
/* how many bytes were read */
size_t rb;
/* the events (up to 64 at once) */
struct input_event ev[64];

rb=read(fd,ev,sizeof(struct input_event)*64);

if (rb < (int) sizeof(struct input_event)) {
    perror("evtest: short read");
    exit (1);
}

for (yalv = 0;
     yalv < (int) (rb / sizeof(struct input_event));
     yalv++)
{
    //if (EV_KEY == ev[yalv].type)
        printf("%ld.%06ld ",
               ev[yalv].time.tv_sec,
               ev[yalv].time.tv_usec,
        printf("type %d code %d value %d\n",
               ev[yalv].type,
               ev[yalv].code, ev[yalv].value);
}
```

Then you should pay attention, what event types are being emitted, and then work with them further.